# start a scene when a user taps a link in a UIWebView in another scene

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I have two scenes. The first one has a UIWebView. Lets say a user taps this link:

```
<a href="startSecondScene">start second scene</a>
```

The second one should appear without the link been loaded in the first one.

ViewController.m code:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

 - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    NSString *urlString = @"http://www.autoblog.com/";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [_udazzWebView loadRequest:urlRequest];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use method from UIWebViewDelegate:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView
shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
 navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    if ([request.URL.absoluteString isEqualToString:@"startSecondScene"]) {
        //go to the second scene
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Do not forget `_udazzWebView.delegate = self;` in your `-viewDidLoad` method.

You can push new scene like so:

```
SecondViewController* _vc = [SecondViewController new];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:_vc animated:YES];
```

for more info about `navigationController` you can read at the documentation:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UINavigationController

Hope it will help.

Comment: OK, but how do I launch the second scene?

Comment: I'm getting: Unknown type name 'SecViewController' did you mean 'UIViewController'?

Comment: When I wrote 'SecondViewController' I mean subclass of 'UIViewController'. You can push 'UIViewController'.